# Translate Curl command to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, curl

The below curl line works in terminal, but I cant figure out how to correctly translate it into NSURL

```
curl -X PUT http://user:pass@localhost:3000/update/564a3f1ff72fe641a8000013/? -d firstName=Adam
```

This is the code I am rocking so far and it connects but creates fields with the value NIL instead of udpateing them with new value

```
NSString *authString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@%c",@"user", @"pass", '@'];

NSData *postData = [@"firstName=Adam" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@localhost:3000/update/564a3f1ff72fe641a8000013/?",authString]];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
[req setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *err = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *res = nil;
NSData *retData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&res error:&err];
if (err)
{
    //handle error
    NSLog(@"BOOO : %@",err);
}
else
{
    //handle response and returning data
    NSLog(@"YAYA : %@",err);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the content type of your request:

```
[req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSMutableURLRequest' declares selector 'setContentType:'

Comment: EDITED - sorry, I wrote how I do it -- as I have a category for that ;) but in the end you wanna set the header

Comment: [req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; That worked for me thank you!!